# Can you get any program in Linux to print a stack trace if it segfaults?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

If I run a program from the shell, and it segfaults:

```
$ buggy_program
Segmentation fault
```

It will tell me, however, is there a way to get programs to print a backtrace, perhaps by running something like this:

```
$ print_backtrace_if_segfault buggy_program
Segfault in main.c:35
(rest of the backtrace)
```

I'd also rather not use strace or ltrace for that kind of information, as they'll print either way...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this kind of automates it.

Put the following in `~/backtrace`:

```
backtrace
quit
```

Put this in a script called `seg_wrapper.sh` in a directory in your path:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -c unlimited
"$@"
if [[ $? -eq 139 ]]; then
    gdb -q $1 core -x ~/backtrace
fi
```

The `ulimit` command makes it so the core is dumped. `"$@"` are the arguments given to the script, so it would be your program and its arguments. `$?` holds the exit status, 139 seems to be the default exit status for my machine for a segfault.

For `gdb`, `-q` means quiet (no intro message), and `-x` tells `gdb` to execute commands in the file given to it.

#### Usage

So to use it you would just:

```
seg_wrapper.sh ./mycommand and its arguments
```

#### Update

You could also write a signal handler that does this, see [this link](http://awhite2008.blog.sohu.com/155611786.html).

Comment: Your link to the signal handler solution is dead - this is why answers should not link to other resources...

Comment: you probably mean "-x tells gdb to execute" instead of "-x tells gdb to exit"

Answer (score 27):

**Edit:**

10 years after I dropped this answer the feature has been deprecated.  So if you find that your system/target does not have `libSegFault.so` seek alternatives.

See [commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=65ccd641bacea33be23d51da737c2de7543d0f5e)

---

Sorry to come in here 2 years later ... stumbled upon while looking for something else.  Adding this for completeness.

1. While I think the accepted answer is great, it requires gdb.  The method I am familiar with uses libSegFault.so.

If you run your app with

> LD_PRELOAD=...path-to.../libSegFault.so myapp

You would get a report with backtrace, loaded libs, etc

2. A wrapper script `catchsegv` is also available that would attempt to use `addr2line` to translate addresses to filename + line number.

These are much lighter solutions than core files or gdb (good for embedded systems for example)

Comment: Actually, `LD_PRELOAD=libSegFault.so` is fine if it is in the dl path.

Comment: @FernandoSilveira ok. Writing the answer this way hints to the reader that they should check what that path is.

Comment: Looks like this feature has been removed from glibc: [The catchsegv script and associated libSegFault.so shared object have been removed.  There are widely-deployed out-of-process alternatives for catching coredumps and backtraces.](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=10111)

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist yeah unfortunately 10 years after I posted my answer they removed the feature - I'll leave my answer but add an edit

Answer (score 7):

[catchsegv](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/debug/catchsegv.sh)

It was mentioned in another answer (but in no way focused on).  It's a handy tool bundled with the glibc project.  It will provide a backtrace (and other useful debug information) *only if* a program does indeed segfault.

A good write up exists [here](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2007/05/22/catching-sigsegvs-as-they-happen/).

You can include it in your own scripts as you see fit.

Comment: curious - how is this not covered by my answer posted 4 years before yours?

Answer (score 6):

You need everyone's friend GDB

```
gdb <program> [core file]
```

Once you've loaded your corefile, the command 'backtrace' (can be abbreviated to bt) will give you the current call stack.  If you run your program from inside gdb, you can set arbitrary breakpoints and examine the memory contents, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to get it just to print the backtrace and exit?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu (as a project) uses Apport to do this.  You can look how they did it.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport

Comment: +1: Apport mentions some useful mechanisms I wasn't familiar with, like `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly modified variant of the script from Kyle Brandt. It is improved in the following ways:

- do not require manual interaction if stack trace is long
- some coredumps are saved with the name pattern core., respect this setting
- do not require an explicit command file flying around for gdb (it will create a temporary one)
- wait for background jobs

## Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gdbcommandfile=$(tempfile)
usepid=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid)
printf "set pagination off\nbacktrace\nquit\n" > $gdbcommandfile
ulimit -c unlimited
"$@"&
pid=$!
wait $!
if [[ $? -eq 139 ]]; then
    if [[ $usepid == 1 ]]; then 
        gdb -q $1 core.$pid -x $gdbcommandfile
    else
        gdb -q $1 core -x $gdbcommandfile
    fi
fi
rm $gdbcommandfile
```

Comment: For a chain of such simple commands, I would just use `-ex` instead.  `gdb ... -ex 'set pagination off' -ex backtrace -ex quit`